# Coerce multiple columns to factors at once

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I have a sample data frame like below:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40), 4, 10, dimnames = list(1:4, LETTERS[1:10])))
```

I want to know how can I select multiple columns and convert them together to factors. I usually do it in the way like `data$A = as.factor(data$A)`. But when the data frame is very large and contains lots of columns, this way will be very time consuming. Does anyone know of a better way to do it?

Comment: All answers here are using function `factor` not `as.factor` (as you did). In fact, using `as.factor` is preferred: [Why use `as.factor()` instead of just `factor()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39279238/4891738)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Choose some columns to coerce to factors:

```
cols <- c("A", "C", "D", "H")
```

Use `lapply()` to coerce and replace the chosen columns:

```
data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], factor)  ## as.factor() could also be used
```

Check the result:

```
sapply(data, class)
#        A         B         C         D         E         F         G 
# "factor" "integer"  "factor"  "factor" "integer" "integer" "integer" 
#        H         I         J 
# "factor" "integer" "integer"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be `data[,cols] <- lapply(data[,cols], factor)` (with the leading comma for columns)?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591- It could be either.  With the comma is a matrix-type subset, without the comma is a list subset.  Data frames can be subsetted by either one so either way would work.

Comment: How can this solution be expanded to include factor levels and labels?

Comment: @Ben - It's probably best to ask a new question

Comment: This is a great solution, and my go-to code now for changing column classes. However, I think using sapply to view the classes is ugly/hard to read. str(data) works better for me.

Comment: To add to Rich Scriven's answer, I had too many columns and didn't want to name all of them. I ended up using indices such as in sample below: cols <- c(2, 5, 7, 14:16) data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], factor)

Comment: @Ben you can specify labels and levels by extending the answer: `data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], factor, levels=c("val1", "val2", ...), labels=c("label1", "label2", ...)` be careful with this though... all of the variables will use the same levels and labels you provide.

Answer (score 40):

Here is an option using `dplyr`.  The `%<>%` operator from `magrittr` update the lhs object with the resulting value.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
cols <- c("A", "C", "D", "H")

data %<>%
       mutate_each_(funs(factor(.)),cols)
str(data)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  10 variables:
# $ A: Factor w/ 4 levels "23","24","26",..: 1 2 3 4
# $ B: int  15 13 39 16
# $ C: Factor w/ 4 levels "3","5","18","37": 2 1 3 4
# $ D: Factor w/ 4 levels "2","6","28","38": 3 1 4 2
# $ E: int  14 4 22 20
# $ F: int  7 19 36 27
# $ G: int  35 40 21 10
# $ H: Factor w/ 4 levels "11","29","32",..: 1 4 3 2
# $ I: int  17 1 9 25
# $ J: int  12 30 8 33
```

---

Or if we are using `data.table`, either use a `for` loop with `set`

```
setDT(data)
for(j in cols){
  set(data, i=NULL, j=j, value=factor(data[[j]]))
}
```

Or we can specify the 'cols' in `.SDcols`  and assign (`:=`) the rhs to 'cols'

```
setDT(data)[, (cols):= lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols=cols]
```

Answer (score 40):

The more recent `tidyverse` way is to use the `mutate_at` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
set.seed(88)

data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40), 4, 10, dimnames = list(1:4, LETTERS[1:10])))
cols <- c("A", "C", "D", "H")

data %<>% mutate_at(cols, factor)
str(data)
 $ A: Factor w/ 4 levels "5","17","18",..: 2 1 4 3   
 $ B: int  36 35 2 26
 $ C: Factor w/ 4 levels "22","31","32",..: 1 2 4 3
 $ D: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","9","16","39": 3 4 1 2
 $ E: int  3 14 30 38
 $ F: int  27 15 28 37
 $ G: int  19 11 6 21
 $ H: Factor w/ 4 levels "7","12","20",..: 1 3 4 2
 $ I: int  23 24 13 8
 $ J: int  10 25 4 33
```

Comment: You don't even need to use `funs` if you only perform one transformation; `mutate_at(cols, factor)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 23):

As of 2021 (still current in early 2023), the current `tidyverse/dplyr` approach would be to use `across`, and a `<tidy-select>` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(across(*<tidy-select>*, *function*))
```

`across(<tidy-select>)` allows very consistent and easy selection of columns to transform.
Some examples:

```
data %>% mutate(across(c(A, B, C, E), as.factor)) # select columns A to C, and E (by name)

data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) # select character columns

data %>% mutate(across(1:5, as.factor)) # select first 5 columns (by index)
```

Comment: can you add your citation for why we need/should use 'across'? I don't see it in R4DS or the ?dplyr page

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html
"across() supersedes the family of "scoped variants" like summarise_at(), summarise_if(), and summarise_all()."

Answer (score 13):

You can use `mutate_if` (`dplyr`):

For example, coerce `integer` in `factor`:

```
mydata=structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = c("a", "a", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
       a     b c    
   <int> <int> <chr>
 1     1     1 a    
 2     2     2 a    
 3     3     3 b    
 4     4     4 b    
 5     5     5 c    
 6     6     6 c    
 7     7     7 c    
 8     8     8 c    
 9     9     9 c    
10    10    10 c
```

Use the function:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata%>%
    mutate_if(is.integer,as.factor)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
       a     b c    
   <fct> <fct> <chr>
 1     1     1 a    
 2     2     2 a    
 3     3     3 b    
 4     4     4 b    
 5     5     5 c    
 6     6     6 c    
 7     7     7 c    
 8     8     8 c    
 9     9     9 c    
10    10    10 c
```

Answer (score 7):

and, for completeness and with regards to [this question asking about changing string columns only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637981/change-several-column-into-factor-r), there's `mutate_if`:

```
data <- cbind(stringVar = sample(c("foo","bar"),10,replace=TRUE),
              data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40), 10, 10, dimnames = list(1:10, LETTERS[1:10]))),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)     

factoredData = data %>% mutate_if(is.character,funs(factor(.)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `data.table` example. I used `grep` in this example because that's how I often select many columns by using partial matches to their names.

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(matrix(sample(1:40), 4, 10, dimnames = list(1:4, LETTERS[1:10])))

factorCols <- grep(pattern = "A|C|D|H", x = names(data), value = TRUE)

data[, (factorCols) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = factorCols]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and updated solution

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate_at(cols, list(~factor(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have another objective of getting in values from the table then using them to be converted, you can try the following way

```
### pre processing
ind <- bigm.train[,lapply(.SD,is.character)]
ind <- names(ind[,.SD[T]])
### Convert multiple columns to factor
bigm.train[,(ind):=lapply(.SD,factor),.SDcols=ind]
```

This selects columns which are specifically character based and then converts them to factor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tidyverse approach using the `modify_at()` function from the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

# Data frame with only integer columns
data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40), 4, 10, dimnames = list(1:4, LETTERS[1:10])))

# Modify specified columns to a factor class
data_with_factors <- data %>%
    purrr::modify_at(c("A", "C", "E"), factor)


# Check the results:
str(data_with_factors)
# 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  10 variables:
#  $ A: Factor w/ 4 levels "8","12","33",..: 1 3 4 2
#  $ B: int  25 32 2 19
#  $ C: Factor w/ 4 levels "5","15","35",..: 1 3 4 2
#  $ D: int  11 7 27 6
#  $ E: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","4","16","20": 2 3 1 4
#  $ F: int  21 23 39 18
#  $ G: int  31 14 38 26
#  $ H: int  17 24 34 10
#  $ I: int  13 28 30 29
#  $ J: int  3 22 37 9
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the use of SAPPLY on a data.frame to convert variables to factors at once does not work as it produces a matrix/ array. My approach is to use LAPPLY instead, as follows.

```
## let us create a data.frame here

class <- c("7", "6", "5", "3")

cash <- c(100, 200, 300, 150)

height <- c(170, 180, 150, 165)

people <- data.frame(class, cash, height)

class(people) ## This is a dataframe 

## We now apply lapply to the data.frame as follows.

bb <- lapply(people, as.factor) %>% data.frame() 

## The lapply part returns a list which we coerce back to a data.frame

class(bb) ## A data.frame

##Now let us check the classes of the variables 

class(bb$class)

class(bb$height)

class(bb$cash) ## as expected, are all factors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you are trying to convert multiple columns with a matching pattern in data:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 40, replace = TRUE), 4, 10, 
                   dimnames = list(1:4, LETTERS[1:10])))
colnames(data) <- c(LETTERS[1:5], paste0(rep("binary_", 5), LETTERS[6:10]))

data <- data %>% 
  mutate_if(grepl("binary", colnames(.)), as.factor)
```