# Why use as.factor() instead of just factor()

Tags: r, r-factor

I recently saw Matt Dowle write some code with `as.factor()`, specifically

```
for (col in names_factors) set(dt, j=col, value=as.factor(dt[[col]]))
```

in [a comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813578/convert-column-classes-in-data-table#comment31200110_20808945).

I used this snippet, but I needed to explicitly set the factor levels to make sure the levels appear in my desired order, so I had to change

```
as.factor(dt[[col]])
```

to

```
factor(dt[[col]], levels = my_levels)
```

This got me thinking: what (if any) is the benefit to using `as.factor()` versus just `factor()`?

Comment: Naming consistency is a big one. Almost all common classes have an `as.class` function.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`as.factor` is a wrapper for `factor`, but it allows quick return if the input vector is already a factor:

```
function (x) 
{
    if (is.factor(x)) 
        x
    else if (!is.object(x) && is.integer(x)) {
        levels <- sort(unique.default(x))
        f <- match(x, levels)
        levels(f) <- as.character(levels)
        if (!is.null(nx <- names(x))) 
        names(f) <- nx
        class(f) <- "factor"
        f
    }
else factor(x)
}
```

---

Comment from [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank): it's not a mere wrapper, since this "quick return" will leave factor levels as they are while `factor()` will not:

```
f = factor("a", levels = c("a", "b"))
#[1] a
#Levels: a b

factor(f)
#[1] a
#Levels: a

as.factor(f)
#[1] a
#Levels: a b
```

---

### Expanded answer two years later, including the following:

- What does the manual say?
- Performance: `as.factor` > `factor` when input is a factor
- Performance: `as.factor` > `factor` when input is integer
- Unused levels or NA levels
- Caution when using R's group-by functions: watch for unused or NA levels

---

#### What does the manual say?

The documentation for `?factor` mentions the following:

```
‘factor(x, exclude = NULL)’ applied to a factor without ‘NA’s is a
 no-operation unless there are unused levels: in that case, a
 factor with the reduced level set is returned.

 ‘as.factor’ coerces its argument to a factor.  It is an
 abbreviated (sometimes faster) form of ‘factor’.
```

#### Performance: `as.factor` > `factor` when input is a factor

The word "no-operation" is a bit ambiguous. Don't take it as "doing nothing"; in fact, it means "doing a lot of things but essentially changing nothing". Here is an example:

```
set.seed(0)
## a randomized long factor with 1e+6 levels, each repeated 10 times
f <- sample(gl(1e+6, 10))

system.time(f1 <- factor(f))  ## default: exclude = NA
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.640   0.216   7.887 

system.time(f2 <- factor(f, exclude = NULL))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.764   0.028   7.791 

system.time(f3 <- as.factor(f))
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 

identical(f, f1)
#[1] TRUE

identical(f, f2)
#[1] TRUE

identical(f, f3)
#[1] TRUE
```

`as.factor` does give a quick return, but `factor` is not a real "no-op". Let's profile `factor` to see what it has done.

```
Rprof("factor.out")
f1 <- factor(f)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("factor.out")[c(1, 4)]
#$by.self
#                      self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"factor"                   4.70    58.90       7.98    100.00
#"unique.default"           1.30    16.29       4.42     55.39
#"as.character"             1.18    14.79       1.84     23.06
#"as.character.factor"      0.66     8.27       0.66      8.27
#"order"                    0.08     1.00       0.08      1.00
#"unique"                   0.06     0.75       4.54     56.89
#
#$sampling.time
#[1] 7.98
```

It first `sort` the `unique` values of the input vector `f`, then converts `f` to a character vector, finally uses `factor` to coerces the character vector back to a factor. Here is the source code of `factor` for confirmation.

```
function (x = character(), levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
    ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA) 
{
    if (is.null(x)) 
        x <- character()
    nx <- names(x)
    if (missing(levels)) {
        y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
        ind <- sort.list(y)
        levels <- unique(as.character(y)[ind])
    }
    force(ordered)
    if (!is.character(x)) 
        x <- as.character(x)
    levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]
    f <- match(x, levels)
    if (!is.null(nx)) 
        names(f) <- nx
    nl <- length(labels)
    nL <- length(levels)
    if (!any(nl == c(1L, nL))) 
        stop(gettextf("invalid 'labels'; length %d should be 1 or %d", 
            nl, nL), domain = NA)
    levels(f) <- if (nl == nL) 
        as.character(labels)
    else paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))
    class(f) <- c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
    f
}
```

So function `factor` is really designed to work with a character vector and it applies `as.character` to its input to ensure that. We can at least learn two performance-related issues from above:

1. For a data frame `DF`, `lapply(DF, as.factor)` is much faster than `lapply(DF, factor)` for type conversion, if many columns are readily factors.
2. That function `factor` is slow can explain why some important R functions are slow, say `table`: [R: table function suprisingly slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51503226/4891738)

#### Performance: `as.factor` > `factor` when input is integer

A factor variable is the next of kin of an integer variable.

```
unclass(gl(2, 2, labels = letters[1:2]))
#[1] 1 1 2 2
#attr(,"levels")
#[1] "a" "b"

storage.mode(gl(2, 2, labels = letters[1:2]))
#[1] "integer"
```

This means that converting an integer to a factor is easier than converting a numeric / character to a factor. `as.factor` just takes care of this.

```
x <- sample.int(1e+6, 1e+7, TRUE)

system.time(as.factor(x))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.592   0.252   4.845 

system.time(factor(x))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 22.236   0.264  22.659
```

#### Unused levels or NA levels

Now let's see a few examples on `factor` and `as.factor`'s influence on factor levels (if the input is a factor already). [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) has given one with unused factor level, I will provide one with `NA` level.

```
f <- factor(c(1, NA), exclude = NULL)
#[1] 1    <NA>
#Levels: 1 <NA>

as.factor(f)
#[1] 1    <NA>
#Levels: 1 <NA>

factor(f, exclude = NULL)
#[1] 1    <NA>
#Levels: 1 <NA>

factor(f)
#[1] 1    <NA>
#Levels: 1
```

There is a (generic) function `droplevels` that can be used to drop unused levels of a factor. But `NA` levels can not be dropped by default.

```
## "factor" method of `droplevels`
droplevels.factor
#function (x, exclude = if (anyNA(levels(x))) NULL else NA, ...) 
#factor(x, exclude = exclude)

droplevels(f)
#[1] 1    <NA>
#Levels: 1 <NA>

droplevels(f, exclude = NA)
#[1] 1    <NA>
#Levels: 1
```

#### Caution when using R's group-by functions: watch for unused or NA levels

R functions doing group-by operations, like `split`, `tapply` expect us to provide factor variables as "by" variables. But often we just provide character or numeric variables. So internally, these functions need to convert them into factors and probably most of them would use `as.factor` in the first place (at least this is so for `split.default` and `tapply`). The `table` function looks like an exception and I spot `factor` instead of `as.factor` inside. There might be some special consideration which is unfortunately not obvious to me when I inspect its source code.

Since most group-by R functions use `as.factor`, if they are given a factor with unused or `NA` levels, such group will appear in the result.

```
x <- c(1, 2)
f <- factor(letters[1:2], levels = letters[1:3])

split(x, f)
#$a
#[1] 1
#
#$b
#[1] 2
#
#$c
#numeric(0)

tapply(x, f, FUN = mean)
# a  b  c 
# 1  2 NA
```

Interestingly, although `table` does not rely on `as.factor`, it preserves those unused levels, too:

```
table(f)
#a b c 
#1 1 0
```

Sometimes this kind of behavior can be undesired. A classic example is `barplot(table(f))`:

[image]

If this is really undesired, we need to manually remove unused or `NA` levels from our factor variable, using `droplevels` or `factor`.

***Hint:***

1. `split` has an argument `drop` which defaults to `FALSE` hence `as.factor` is used; by `drop = TRUE` function `factor` is used instead.
2. `aggregate` relies on `split`, so it also has a `drop` argument and it defaults to `TRUE`.
3. `tapply` does not have `drop` although it also relies on `split`. In particular the documentation `?tapply` says that `as.factor` is (always) used.

Comment: The source code for function `factor` in the answer is under R 3.4.4. The source code has changed a lot since R 3.5.0, but all conclusions in the answer are still valid.