# R: table function suprisingly slow

Tags: r

```
> class(v)
"numeric"
> length(v)
80373285   # 80 million
```

The entries of `v` are **integers** uniformly distributed between 0 and 100.

```
> ptm  <-  proc.time()
> tv   <-  table(v)
> show(proc.time() - ptm)
   user  system elapsed 
 96.902   0.807  97.761
```

Why is the `table` function so slow on this vector?

Is there a faster function for this simple operation?

By comparison, the  `bigtable` function from `bigtabulate` is fast:

```
> library(bigtabulate)
> ptm  <-  proc.time() ;  bt <- bigtable(x = matrix(v,ncol=1), ccols=1) ; show(proc.time() - ptm)
   user  system elapsed 
  4.163   0.120   4.286
```

While `bigtabulate` is a good solution, it seems unwieldy to resort to a special package just for this simple function. Technically, there is overhead because I am contorting a vector into a matrix to make it work with `bigtable`.  Shouldn't there be simpler, faster solution in base `R`?

For whatever its worth, the base `R` function `cumsum` is extremely fast even for this long vector:

```
> ptm  <-  proc.time() ; cs   <-  cumsum(v) ; show(proc.time() - ptm)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.097   0.117   0.214
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it calls `factor` first. Try `tabulate` if all your entries are integers. But you need to plus 1, so that the vector values start from 1 not 0.