# Counting number of occurences in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I need to count the number of values occurrences in the entire matrix.

My matrix consists only of `"0"` `"1"` `"2"` and I need my result to be the sum of occurrences of each of the values

If this is my matrix:

[image]

The result should be:

0 -> `10` 1 -> `9` 2-> `11`

I am looking for an answer that uses apply. I feel like I've searched half of the internet but I didn't stumble across an answer that would be understandable or recreatable.

I ultimately want to make this apply work parallel but I think I know how to do this.

I should mention that my matrix is 30e6x18 and table is not working because of the memory issue I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your matrix is large, then it makes sense to compute counts rowwise or columnwise to conserve memory. `apply` is a valid way to go about this.

Conceptually, this answer is not unlike the one I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70898885/12685768) for data frames. I will once again recommend that you use `tabulate` instead of `table`; it is really *much* more efficient.

```r
set.seed(1L)
m <- 5L
n <- 4L
A <- matrix(sample(c("0", "1", "2"), size = m * n, replace = TRUE), m, n)
A
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "0"  "2"  "2"  "1" 
[2,] "2"  "2"  "0"  "1" 
[3,] "0"  "1"  "0"  "1" 
[4,] "1"  "1"  "0"  "2" 
[5,] "0"  "2"  "1"  "0"
```

```r
f <- function(x, levels) tabulate(factor(x, levels), length(levels))

rowSums(apply(A, 1L, f, c("0", "1", "2"))) # if 'm' has more columns than rows
## [1] 7 7 6

rowSums(apply(A, 2L, f, c("0", "1", "2"))) # if 'm' has more rows than columns
## [1] 7 7 6
```

You are going to want `apply` to loop over the smaller dimension of your matrix, so choose the second argument accordingly. If your matrix actually has millions of rows and only 18 columns, then use the second statement above, not the first.

Here is a test using a matrix with your dimensions. It only takes ~10 seconds on my machine, so parallelization might be overkill.

```r
set.seed(1L)
m <- 3e+07L
n <- 18L
A <- matrix(sample(c("0", "1", "2"), m * n, replace = TRUE), m, n)

system.time(rowSums(apply(A, 2L, f, c("0", "1", "2"))))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   8.195   2.816  12.322
```

Just for fun:

```r
library("parallel")
system.time(Reduce(`+`, mclapply(seq_len(n), function(i) f(A[, i], c("0", "1", "2")), mc.cores = 4L)))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   3.924   0.904   3.497
```

Answer (score 3):

Usual way would be to `unlist` (if it is a `data.frame`) and apply the `table` or concatenate (`c` - if it is `matrix` to convert to vector) and apply the `table`.

```
table(unlist(m1))

 0  1  2 
10  9 11
```

---

If the dataset is really big, we can loop.  Here, the number of columns seems to be `30e6` and the number of rows as 18.  We may loop over the rows with a `for` loop and update on a temporary dataset created

```
out <- setNames(rep(0, 3), 0:2)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) {
       tmp <- table(m1[i, ])
       out[names(tmp)] <- out[names(tmp)] + tmp
  }
out
 0  1  2 
10  9 11
```

---

If we need a `parallel` option, can use `dapply` with `parallel = TRUE`, and do a `colSums` on the output generated

```
library(collapse)
colSums(dapply(m1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(x) 
   table(factor(x, levels = 0:2)), parallel = TRUE))
X1 X2 X3 
10  9 11
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("X1", "X2", "X3")))
```