# Different result in the case of `factor` or `as.factor`?

Tags: r

My system is R 3.5.3 with Rstudio 1.1.463

Set dataframe as below:

```
df <- data.frame(
    cola = c('a','b','c','d','e','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
    colb = c("A",NA,"C","D",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cats<-c('a','b','c','d','e','f','1')
```

Then,run `df['cola'] <- lapply(df['cola'], function(x) factor(x,levels=cats,exclude = NULL,ordered = FALSE,nmax=6))`,get the expect result.

If **change `factor` to `as.factor`** based [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279238/why-use-as-factor-instead-of-just-factor),run `df['cola'] <- lapply(df['cola'], function(x) as.factor(x,levels=cats,exclude = NULL,ordered = FALSE,nmax=6))`,will get error as below:

```
Error in as.factor(x, levels = cats, exclude = NULL, ordered = FALSE,  : 
  unused arguments (levels = cats, exclude = NULL, ordered = FALSE, nmax = 6)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: These arguments are in `factor` not `as.factor`.

Comment: `as.factor is a wrapper for factor` in that post mislead me

Comment: This means that `as.factor` does what you manually do in `factor` "automatically".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is as stated in the error message. You are passing arguments which are not present for `as.factor`. If you read `?as.factor` you see the parameter to `as.factor` is only `x`. `levels`, `exclude`, `ordered`, `nmax` are arguments for `factor` and not `as.factor`. Hence, it is giving you error that you are passing arguments which you are not using.

If you remove those arguments and run the function then it works without any error message.

```
lapply(df['cola'], function(x) as.factor(x))
#$cola
# [1] a    b    c    d    e    e    1    <NA> c    d   
#Levels: 1 a b c d e
```

OR just

```
lapply(df['cola'], as.factor)
```

and if you have just one column no need for `lapply`

```
as.factor(df$cola)
```