# Insert column of numbering based on within-grouping index/level in R

Tags: r, for-loop, grouping, tidyverse, apply

I have a tibble of 401 rows. There are more columns in my full dataset but I have provided below only the ones relevant to my question.

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Week, Date, Observer [1]
   Week Date       Observer StartTime   ord
  <int> <date>     <fct>    <fct>     <dbl>
1     1 2020-07-08 IF       05:10         3
2     1 2020-07-08 IF       05:37        12
3     1 2020-07-08 IF       06:06        27
4     1 2020-07-08 IF       06:35        47
5     1 2020-07-08 IF       07:01        68
6     1 2020-07-08 IF       07:29        93
```

`Week` runs from 1 to 13, `Date` has 2-3 unique values for each `Week`, `Observer` has two values "IF" and "KT" for unique `Date`, and `StartTime` has up to 10 unique values for unique `Observer`. My aim is to create a column, `ord` here, of numbers 1-10 based on the grouping by Week, Date and Observer. In other words, I want to number the (up to) 10 unique values of `StartTime` for unique `Week`-`Date`-`Observer` combinations.

e.g., the date 2020-07-08 should have 1-10 numbering for "IF" and also 1-10 for "KT". Then, it should repeat for 2020-07-09 and the rest. But additionally, in case there are less than 10 unique values (say 6), the numbering should start at 1 and end at the appropriate number (6).

In the example I have provided, I used `summarise(ord = as.numeric(unique(StartTime))` after the grouping and this seems to be the best result so far, as it gets the grouping right and only the individual values are wrong (*3, 12, 27, ...* instead of *1, 2, 3, ..., 10*). On the other hand, when I tried things like `summarise(ord = levels(unique(StartTime))` or `summarise(ord = 1:n_distinct(StartTime))`, the results weren't even close to what I wanted.

I have tried for-loops and the *apply functions, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how exactly to use them for my particular requirement. Any help and nudge towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

`dput(df)` below:

```
structure(list(Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L), Date = structure(c(18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 
18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 
18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18451, 18452, 18452, 18452, 
18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 
18452, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 
18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 
18457, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 
18458, 18458, 18458, 18458, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 
18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 
18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18465, 18466, 18466, 18466, 
18466, 18466, 18466, 18466, 18466, 18466, 18466, 18471, 18471, 
18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 
18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18471, 18473, 
18473, 18473, 18473, 18473, 18473, 18473, 18473, 18473, 18473, 
18473, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 
18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 18480, 
18480, 18481, 18481, 18481, 18481, 18481, 18481, 18481, 18481, 
18481, 18481, 18481, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 
18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 
18486, 18486, 18486, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 
18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18487, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 
18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 
18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18494, 18495, 18495, 
18495, 18495, 18495, 18495, 18495, 18495, 18495, 18495, 18495, 
18495, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 
18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 18500, 
18500, 18500, 18500, 18501, 18501, 18501, 18501, 18501, 18501, 
18501, 18501, 18501, 18501, 18501, 18501, 18507, 18507, 18507, 
18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 
18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18508, 
18508, 18508, 18508, 18508, 18508, 18508, 18508, 18508, 18508, 
18508, 18508, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 
18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 18515, 
18515, 18515, 18515, 18516, 18516, 18516, 18516, 18516, 18516, 
18516, 18516, 18516, 18516, 18516, 18516, 18521, 18521, 18521, 
18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 
18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18521, 18522, 18522, 
18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 
18522, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 
18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 18527, 
18527, 18527, 18527, 18529, 18529, 18529, 18529, 18529, 18529, 
18529, 18529, 18529, 18529, 18529, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 
18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 
18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18535, 18536, 18536, 
18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 18536, 
18536), class = "Date"), Observer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("IF", 
"KT"), class = "factor"), StartTime = structure(c(3L, 12L, 27L, 
47L, 68L, 93L, 109L, 130L, 152L, 173L, 1L, 11L, 30L, 50L, 76L, 
102L, 124L, 152L, 176L, 9L, 25L, 43L, 61L, 83L, 105L, 1L, 17L, 
45L, 84L, 114L, 136L, 167L, 4L, 16L, 35L, 79L, 100L, 118L, 140L, 
158L, 1L, 7L, 26L, 48L, 73L, 101L, 121L, 145L, 167L, 189L, 5L, 
16L, 35L, 53L, 79L, 100L, 2L, 13L, 31L, 56L, 82L, 107L, 6L, 19L, 
39L, 57L, 80L, 101L, 120L, 143L, 160L, 180L, 1L, 7L, 24L, 43L, 
67L, 94L, 118L, 147L, 169L, 189L, 8L, 21L, 78L, 100L, 1L, 10L, 
28L, 52L, 82L, 107L, 8L, 23L, 41L, 62L, 86L, 105L, 121L, 159L, 
178L, 7L, 22L, 41L, 65L, 92L, 114L, 141L, 164L, 184L, 198L, 7L, 
20L, 59L, 81L, 102L, 7L, 24L, 44L, 66L, 92L, 111L, 12L, 26L, 
42L, 61L, 82L, 103L, 158L, 178L, 14L, 28L, 46L, 67L, 92L, 110L, 
135L, 159L, 182L, 195L, 16L, 34L, 71L, 94L, 109L, 14L, 29L, 54L, 
80L, 103L, 128L, 15L, 33L, 54L, 74L, 113L, 133L, 171L, 188L, 
16L, 35L, 58L, 83L, 104L, 125L, 149L, 174L, 192L, 207L, 18L, 
34L, 56L, 75L, 114L, 16L, 36L, 56L, 76L, 102L, 122L, 25L, 43L, 
64L, 85L, 105L, 124L, 145L, 163L, 181L, 193L, 24L, 41L, 63L, 
88L, 109L, 132L, 153L, 175L, 191L, 207L, 30L, 47L, 67L, 88L, 
106L, 130L, 24L, 47L, 71L, 96L, 123L, 146L, 33L, 52L, 72L, 94L, 
111L, 131L, 152L, 172L, 190L, 202L, 32L, 49L, 72L, 97L, 117L, 
145L, 166L, 188L, 202L, 214L, 60L, 80L, 101L, 116L, 139L, 155L, 
32L, 52L, 77L, 100L, 120L, 146L, 37L, 55L, 74L, 97L, 113L, 134L, 
151L, 171L, 190L, 203L, 38L, 58L, 83L, 104L, 124L, 147L, 170L, 
191L, 206L, 216L, 42L, 63L, 100L, 115L, 136L, 154L, 38L, 58L, 
92L, 111L, 136L, 161L, 44L, 66L, 89L, 107L, 128L, 147L, 167L, 
202L, 213L, 46L, 70L, 97L, 115L, 137L, 160L, 184L, 199L, 212L, 
220L, 48L, 69L, 96L, 115L, 139L, 157L, 46L, 70L, 94L, 112L, 135L, 
160L, 53L, 73L, 95L, 112L, 132L, 159L, 178L, 191L, 204L, 51L, 
74L, 99L, 117L, 144L, 165L, 185L, 199L, 211L, 218L, 53L, 102L, 
123L, 143L, 159L, 180L, 51L, 80L, 111L, 138L, 162L, 185L, 59L, 
81L, 101L, 117L, 138L, 155L, 177L, 191L, 205L, 215L, 59L, 82L, 
105L, 127L, 150L, 177L, 194L, 208L, 217L, 221L, 60L, 81L, 103L, 
141L, 197L, 62L, 87L, 112L, 135L, 158L, 182L, 69L, 91L, 108L, 
126L, 147L, 168L, 186L, 199L, 209L, 217L, 67L, 92L, 113L, 135L, 
156L, 180L, 196L, 210L, 219L, 222L, 68L, 90L, 110L, 129L, 148L, 
167L, 67L, 95L, 131L, 156L, 183L, 201L), .Label = c("05:00", 
"05:03", "05:10", "05:22", "05:23", "05:25", "05:30", "05:31", 
"05:32", "05:35", "05:36", "05:37", "05:38", "05:40", "05:48", 
"05:50", "05:51", "05:52", "05:53", "05:56", "05:57", "05:58", 
"05:59", "06:00", "06:02", "06:03", "06:06", "06:07", "06:08", 
"06:10", "06:11", "06:12", "06:15", "06:16", "06:17", "06:18", 
"06:19", "06:22", "06:23", "06:25", "06:26", "06:27", "06:28", 
"06:30", "06:32", "06:34", "06:35", "06:37", "06:38", "06:39", 
"06:40", "06:41", "06:42", "06:43", "06:44", "06:45", "06:48", 
"06:49", "06:50", "06:51", "06:52", "06:53", "06:54", "06:55", 
"06:56", "06:58", "07:00", "07:01", "07:02", "07:03", "07:05", 
"07:06", "07:07", "07:08", "07:09", "07:11", "07:12", "07:13", 
"07:14", "07:15", "07:16", "07:17", "07:18", "07:19", "07:20", 
"07:21", "07:22", "07:23", "07:25", "07:26", "07:27", "07:28", 
"07:29", "07:31", "07:33", "07:34", "07:35", "07:36", "07:37", 
"07:40", "07:41", "07:42", "07:43", "07:45", "07:46", "07:49", 
"07:51", "07:52", "07:55", "07:56", "07:57", "07:58", "08:00", 
"08:02", "08:03", "08:05", "08:06", "08:07", "08:08", "08:09", 
"08:11", "08:12", "08:13", "08:14", "08:15", "08:16", "08:18", 
"08:19", "08:20", "08:22", "08:23", "08:24", "08:25", "08:26", 
"08:28", "08:29", "08:30", "08:31", "08:32", "08:33", "08:35", 
"08:36", "08:37", "08:38", "08:39", "08:41", "08:43", "08:45", 
"08:47", "08:49", "08:50", "08:51", "08:52", "08:54", "08:56", 
"08:57", "08:58", "08:59", "09:00", "09:01", "09:02", "09:03", 
"09:04", "09:06", "09:07", "09:09", "09:10", "09:12", "09:13", 
"09:15", "09:16", "09:17", "09:18", "09:19", "09:20", "09:22", 
"09:23", "09:24", "09:25", "09:26", "09:28", "09:29", "09:31", 
"09:34", "09:35", "09:36", "09:37", "09:41", "09:42", "09:44", 
"09:48", "09:49", "09:53", "09:55", "09:57", "09:58", "09:59", 
"10:01", "10:03", "10:06", "10:08", "10:09", "10:11", "10:12", 
"10:14", "10:17", "10:18", "10:26", "10:29", "10:30", "10:31", 
"10:33", "10:34", "10:37", "10:39", "10:45", "10:55", "11:00", 
"11:02", "11:03", "11:24", "11:32"), class = "factor"), ord = c(3, 
12, 27, 47, 68, 93, 109, 130, 152, 173, 1, 11, 30, 50, 76, 102, 
124, 152, 176, 9, 25, 43, 61, 83, 105, 1, 17, 45, 84, 114, 136, 
167, 4, 16, 35, 79, 100, 118, 140, 158, 1, 7, 26, 48, 73, 101, 
121, 145, 167, 189, 5, 16, 35, 53, 79, 100, 2, 13, 31, 56, 82, 
107, 6, 19, 39, 57, 80, 101, 120, 143, 160, 180, 1, 7, 24, 43, 
67, 94, 118, 147, 169, 189, 8, 21, 78, 100, 1, 10, 28, 52, 82, 
107, 8, 23, 41, 62, 86, 105, 121, 159, 178, 7, 22, 41, 65, 92, 
114, 141, 164, 184, 198, 7, 20, 59, 81, 102, 7, 24, 44, 66, 92, 
111, 12, 26, 42, 61, 82, 103, 158, 178, 14, 28, 46, 67, 92, 110, 
135, 159, 182, 195, 16, 34, 71, 94, 109, 14, 29, 54, 80, 103, 
128, 15, 33, 54, 74, 113, 133, 171, 188, 16, 35, 58, 83, 104, 
125, 149, 174, 192, 207, 18, 34, 56, 75, 114, 16, 36, 56, 76, 
102, 122, 25, 43, 64, 85, 105, 124, 145, 163, 181, 193, 24, 41, 
63, 88, 109, 132, 153, 175, 191, 207, 30, 47, 67, 88, 106, 130, 
24, 47, 71, 96, 123, 146, 33, 52, 72, 94, 111, 131, 152, 172, 
190, 202, 32, 49, 72, 97, 117, 145, 166, 188, 202, 214, 60, 80, 
101, 116, 139, 155, 32, 52, 77, 100, 120, 146, 37, 55, 74, 97, 
113, 134, 151, 171, 190, 203, 38, 58, 83, 104, 124, 147, 170, 
191, 206, 216, 42, 63, 100, 115, 136, 154, 38, 58, 92, 111, 136, 
161, 44, 66, 89, 107, 128, 147, 167, 202, 213, 46, 70, 97, 115, 
137, 160, 184, 199, 212, 220, 48, 69, 96, 115, 139, 157, 46, 
70, 94, 112, 135, 160, 53, 73, 95, 112, 132, 159, 178, 191, 204, 
51, 74, 99, 117, 144, 165, 185, 199, 211, 218, 53, 102, 123, 
143, 159, 180, 51, 80, 111, 138, 162, 185, 59, 81, 101, 117, 
138, 155, 177, 191, 205, 215, 59, 82, 105, 127, 150, 177, 194, 
208, 217, 221, 60, 81, 103, 141, 197, 62, 87, 112, 135, 158, 
182, 69, 91, 108, 126, 147, 168, 186, 199, 209, 217, 67, 92, 
113, 135, 156, 180, 196, 210, 219, 222, 68, 90, 110, 129, 148, 
167, 67, 95, 131, 156, 183, 201)), row.names = c(NA, -401L), groups = structure(list(
    Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), Date = structure(c(18451, 
    18451, 18452, 18452, 18457, 18457, 18458, 18458, 18465, 18465, 
    18466, 18466, 18471, 18471, 18473, 18473, 18480, 18480, 18481, 
    18481, 18486, 18486, 18487, 18487, 18494, 18494, 18495, 18495, 
    18500, 18500, 18501, 18501, 18507, 18507, 18508, 18508, 18515, 
    18515, 18516, 18516, 18521, 18521, 18522, 18522, 18527, 18527, 
    18529, 18529, 18535, 18535, 18536, 18536), class = "Date"), 
    Observer = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("IF", 
    "KT"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:10, 11:19, 
        20:25, 26:32, 33:40, 41:50, 51:56, 57:62, 63:72, 73:82, 
        83:86, 87:92, 93:101, 102:111, 112:116, 117:122, 123:130, 
        131:140, 141:145, 146:151, 152:159, 160:169, 170:174, 
        175:180, 181:190, 191:200, 201:206, 207:212, 213:222, 
        223:232, 233:238, 239:244, 245:254, 255:264, 265:270, 
        271:276, 277:285, 286:295, 296:301, 302:307, 308:316, 
        317:326, 327:332, 333:338, 339:348, 349:358, 359:363, 
        364:369, 370:379, 380:389, 390:395, 396:401), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 52L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your data seems to have no duplicate, then `mutate(ord=row_number())` just works well.

Comment: @yh6 Sorry for that. My original data has many duplicates of `Week`, `Date`, `Observer` and `StartTime`--as many rows as the number of observations made. The example I provided does not have duplicates because of the `summarise()` function I used but I would like for the solution to work such that the duplicate rows have the same value of `ord` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using factor for hour but getting only the index..

```
df %>%
  group_by(
    Week, 
    Date, 
    Observer
  ) %>%
  summarise(
    StartTime = StartTime
  ) %>%
  arrange(
    StartTime
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    ord = as.integer(factor(StartTime))
  ) %>%
  arrange(
    Week, Date, Observer
  ) %>% View()
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it seems to be working. Could you please clarify the following: (1) `mutate(ord = as.integer(factor(StartTime)))` is the main player here? You mentioned "getting only the index" which I failed to understand. Also, `summarise()` instead of `mutate()` wouldn't be wrong, would it?. 
(2) `summarise(StartTime = StartTime)` in your code is simply to remove the `ord` column and has no other function?
(3) The documentation of `arrange()` states that it doesn't respect grouping by default, so is it necessary to specify it here, or does the upstream `group_by()` get passed on?

Comment: when mutating an attribute to a factor `ord = factor(StartTime)` , R creates an index for each different StartTime value (see R factors for more details), although it shows the referenced value instead of the index. Casting to integer, `ord = as.integer(factor(StartTime))` explicit retrieves the index not the indexed value. It works because of the grouping criteria used before.

Comment: Understood, but what difference would using `as.factor()` instead of `factor()` make? This was one of the options I tried earlier.

Comment: "as.factor"  seems not to be just a wrapper to "factor". There are differences. There's a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279238/why-use-as-factor-instead-of-just-factor