# Change several column into factor - R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 203 column. 
Some of them string and I want to convert them to factor.

like this :

```
data$var =  as.factor((data$var))
```

The problem is, there is 180 string column. Is there a way to do this with a loop or a sapply maybe ? Anything that can help me to not writing this code 180 times.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180058/coerce-multiple-columns-to-factors-at-once

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue to convert into numeric.

The solution for me was to use the following:

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```