# Converting DF columns to factor is less than straightforward

Tags: r, variables, type-conversion

I'm learning R and would welcome some explanation/pointers as to what the error means and why it is that I can't simply assign the columns as factors:

In R, I `read.csv()` a file into a variable DF. `class(DF)` tells me it's a  "data.frame" but columns 1, 2, and 3 are non-factors. When I try to assign columns 1,2,3 as factors I get an error:

```
asFactors <- c(1:3)
DF[asFactors] <- as.factors(DF[asFactors]) # same if I use DF[,asFactors] 
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

What does sort have to do with me trying to change variable type?

Instead, what I seem to need to do is use an `apply()` function to convert columns to factors (but this isn't the most intuitive thing):

```
DF[,asFactors] <- lapply(DF[asFactors], factor)
```

Furthermore, if I try to convert columns to 4,5,6 to numeric using lapply i get a new error:

```
asNumeric <- c(4:6)
DF[,asNumeric] <- lapply(DF[asNumeric], numeric) 
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'length' argument
```

And if I fall back on my original attempt, I get:

```
DF[,asNumeric] <- as.numeric(DF[,asNumeric])
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So for each variable type I seems= to need a different method of converting columns, or I haven't found the one method that applies to all of them.

Comment: `lapply` should work.  You probably have problems in the data.  Provide a reproducible example for people to work with.

Comment: OK. Where is the duplicate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180058/coerce-multiple-columns-to-factors-at-once

Comment: lapply does work for factors but not for numeric. I take it you mean there may be issues with the numeric data.

Comment: @val - the function is `as.numeric` not `numeric`

Comment: @thelatemail: that was it. Why isn't it consistent with "factor" in the first case? factor and numeric or as.factor and as.numeric would make more sense to me.

Comment: @val - `as.factor` also exists. It just so happens that `factor` is able to generate a factor given your input.

Comment: You should study `help("[")`. Your first attempt doesn't work, because it tries to convert a data.frame to factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change multiple columns to factor, use:

```
DF[,1:3] <- lapply(DF[,1:3], factor)
```

To change from factor to numeric, remember to use as.numeric(as.character(x)), like this:

```
DF[,1:3] <- lapply(DF[,1:3], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: lapply did work for factors but not for numeric.

Comment: @val - See if the above works for converting to numeric now.