# How to fix "Error in `$<-.data.frame` replacement has x rows, data has y"?

Tags: r

My goal is to make a for loop to convert some specific columns of my dataset into either factors or integers.

The condition is going to be based on the name of the column.

```
# Here is a small reproducible dataset
df <- data.frame(x = c(10,20,30), y = c("yes", "no", "no"), z = c("Big", "Small", "Average"))

# here is a vector that we are going to use inside our if statement
column_factor_names <- c("y", "z")

# for each column in df
for (i in names(df)) {

    print(i)

    # if it's a factor, convert into factor, else convert it into integer

    if (i %in% column_factor_names) {
        print("it's a factor")
        df$i <- as.factor(df$i)
    } else {
        print("it's an integer")
        df$i <- as.integer(df$i)
    }
}
```

When I run this I get : `` Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "i", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3 ``

The problem is with the line `df$i <- as.factor(df$i)` and `df$i <- as.integer(df$i)` in the if-else statement.

But what I don't understand, is that when I run this manually.
For example:

```
df$"x" <- as.integer(df$"x")
df$"y" <- as.factor(df$"y")
df$"z" <- as.factor(df$"z")

str(df)
```

It is working:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int  10 20 30
 $ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 1 1
 $ z: Factor w/ 3 levels "Average","Big",..: 2 3 1
```

My question is: why is it not working in the for-loop and if statement?

Comment: No need for `forloop`, Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180265/680068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the subset function `$` looks for a column named `i` instead of evaluating `i`. You can choose to subset the data.frame differently either with `[, i]` or `[[i]]`:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c(10,20,30), y = c("yes", "no", "no"), z = c("Big", "Small", "Average"))

# here is a vector that we are going to use inside our if statement
column_factor_names <- c("y", "z")

# for each column in df
for (i in names(df)) {

  print(i)

  # if it's a factor, convert into factor, else convert it into integer

  if (i %in% column_factor_names) {
    print("it's a factor")
    x[[i]] <- as.factor(x[[i]])
  } else {
    print("it's an integer")
    x[[i]] <- as.integer(x[[i]])
  }
}
```

See `help("$")` for more infos.

If you don't mind loosing the status message you could also do it without the need for a loop:

```
x[, i] <- as.factor(x[, i])
```

Comment: See `help("$")`.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected code for you for loop section is:

```
# Here is a small reproducible dataset
df <- data.frame(x = c(10,20,30), y = c("yes", "no", "no"), z = c("Big", "Small", "Average"))

# here is a vector that we are going to use inside our if statement
column_factor_names <- c("y", "z")

for (i in names(df)) {
    print(i)
    if (i %in% column_factor_names) {
        print("it's a factor")
        df[,i] <- as.factor(df[,i])
    } else {
        print("it's an integer")
        df[,i] <- as.numeric(df[,i])
    }
 }
```